# Using External SMTP Wordpress on VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, email, smtp, vps

I've installed Webmin on my VPS server and also installed Postfix for outgoing mail. I use Ubuntu as Operating System

I use SMTP Plugin for my wordpress site. I've set the SMTP Settings with Zoho SMTP and I'm sure all setting are OK.

When I try to send message with SMTP test email Wordpress plugin, I got this message

```
The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2017-08-22 14:27:26 Connection: opening to smtp.zoho.com:587, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2017-08-22 14:27:26 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
2017-08-22 14:27:26 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.zoho.com:587 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution)
2017-08-22 14:27:26 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (0)
2017-08-22 14:27:26 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I've research for the problem above but not going have any solution for this. But, I'm really sure the problem is in my VPS mail setting and I'm not sure what setting I need to change to fix this SMTP issue.

Answer (score 0):

try connect to your smtp server with this commands:

```
telnet hostname 25
```

Or with ssl

```
openssl s_client -connect hostname:25 -starttls smtp
```

Change port to 587 if you need. And see what is happen.

You can send emails without smtp server from wordpress try this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/blastex/